# Multiline text as the button label in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, button, word-wrap, shapes

Basically, I am creating a button in an oval shape. But my button label is too long to display in one line, so I wanted to split it into multiple lines so that the oval button looks good.

How do I enable word wrap on a button?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Set the label text on form load and add Environment.Newline as the newline string, like this:

```
btnOK.Text = "OK" + Environment.NewLine + "true";
```

Comment: That's correct, but one can improve on it slightly:  Set the text exactly that way in the Designer file.  That way, the Form Designer GUI will show it correctly, which can help in positioning and sizing.

Answer (score 40):

If you want to set a button's label to multi-line text inside the VS designer, you can click on the "down arrow" at the right of the property field and then you are able to enter multiple lines of text.

[image: VS text multiline property panel]

I tried this in VS 2015.

Comment: You're welcome. I was surprised myself that I didn't realize for a long time that little arrow existed there.

Comment: ahah so simple!

Answer (score 3):

Just add a newline in the text at the place where it should split.

Comment: @Dimesh, and if you make your button a little bigger (or test with a smaller font)?

Comment: Alt-Enter? Shift-Enter? Ctrl-Enter? One of those should work, you'll see the value visually split into two lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "\n" to button's Text property in the places you want to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. If you are creating a custom control, then place a label control on it with the `Autosize = true` option. And adjust its size as per the buttons size.
2. Add a new line wherever you want (a bit crude).

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom Button with one additional property (say, `Label`) which converts "\n" occurrence into "real" newline (because VS designer cannot do it already 10 years):

```
public string Label
{
    get { return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text) ? Text : Text.Replace("\n", @"\n")); }
    set {
        Text = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value : value.Replace(@"\n", "\n"));
    }
}
```

Once you created such class, your SuperButton will be visible in Toolbox at Project page, so you don't loose visual way of design.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to insert a line break  (i.e. \n) in the button text.

Example:

```
Button1.AutoSize = true;

Button1.Text = "This is \n The Button Text";
```