# How to retrieve text from datagridview cell and displayit in the button?

Tags: c#, winforms, text, button, multiline

How can I retrieve text from DataGridView Cell and displayit on the button.
Basically I have two forms on my project (Form1 & Form2).

-In **Form1** I have two buttons (Starter & Main). Both these buttons on click event, they call database sql-query and genereate into form the records as buttons.

-In **Form2** I have a button (Starter). Also this button on click event calls database sql-query and generates records in DatagridView.

Now in **Form2** when I double_click inside the cell under the **Quantity In Stock** column, a dialog-box pops up and allows me to enter the number in to that particular cell. **Lets say Row-1:**

```
Soup     Starter     10     <Allways On Stock>
```

---

So based on this, how can I take the value of that **cell = 10** and dispalyit on the bottom-right corner of the Button (in this case button Soup)
Like So:

```
##############
#            #
#   Soup     #
#         10 #
##############
```

Could someone help me please and solve this problem....

Thanks in advance...

Kind regards

lapeci

---

here is the code of cellclick event of datagridview

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            // make sure that the click was in the right column
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)  // I used 1 here because I didn't put a column for FoodType, you should use 2.
            {
                // Give it a value in case the cell is empty
                string cellContent = "0";
                if (this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != null)
                {
                    cellContent = this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                }

                using (InputBox ib = new InputBox("Enter new stock amount:", this.dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(), cellContent))
                {
                    if (ib.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = ib.Result;
                        cellContent = ib.Result;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And this is the InputBox dialog to enter quantity in to the cell...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DtposApplication
{
    public partial class InputBox : Form
    {
        public InputBox(string text, string caption, string defaultValue)
        {
            //
            // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
            //
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Text = caption;  //.Clone().ToString();


            Size size;
            using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
            {
                Rectangle screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
                SizeF sizeF = g.MeasureString(text, lblPrompt.Font, screen.Width - 20);
                size = sizeF.ToSize();
                size.Width += 4;
            }

            if (size.Width < 310)
            {
                size.Width = 310;
            }
            Size clientSize = this.ClientSize;
            clientSize.Width += size.Width - lblPrompt.Width;
            clientSize.Height += size.Height - lblPrompt.Height;
            this.ClientSize = clientSize;
            lblPrompt.Text = text;
            txtResult.Text = defaultValue;
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        }

        void CancelButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            result = null;
            this.Close();
        }

        void AcceptButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            result = txtResult.Text;
            this.Close();
        }

        string result;

        public string Result
        {
            get
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        private void btnSeven_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtResult.Text += btnSeven.Text + "7";
        }

        private void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtResult.Text += btnTwo.Text + "2";
        }

        private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtResult.Text += btnOne.Text + "1";
        }

        private void btnSix_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtResult.Text += btnSix.Text + "6";
        }

        private void btnFive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtResult.Text += btnFive.Text + "5";
        }

        private void btnFour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtResult.Text += btnFour.Text + "4";
        }

        private void btnNine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtResult.Text += btnNine.Text + "9";
        }

        private void btnEight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtResult.Text += btnEight.Text + "8";
        }

        private void btnThree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtResult.Text += btnThree.Text + "3";
        }

        private void btnZero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtResult.Text += btnZero.Text + "0";
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtResult.Clear();
            txtResult.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

is the code how im creating buttons on form1 and then take the database records and asign values to these buttons

---

```
private void FoodAddButtons(DataTable table)
        {
            int xpos = 5;
            int ypos = 5;
            int space = 2;
            VistaButtonTest.VistaButton newButton = null;
            DtposMenuBS.Sort = "FoodPrice";
            try
            {
                foreach (DataRowView dr in DtposMenuBS.List)
                {
                    newButton = new VistaButtonTest.VistaButton();
                    newButton.ButtonText = dr["FoodName"].ToString();
                    newButton.AutoEllipsis = true;
                    newButton.Width = 152;
                    newButton.Height = 70;
                    newButton.CornerRadius = 4;
                    newButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial Narrow", 15.00F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                    newButton.BaseColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
                    newButton.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                    newButton.HighlightColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
                    newButton.GlowColor = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
                    if (xpos + newButton.Width > this.FoodMenuPanel.ClientSize.Width)
                    {
                        ypos += newButton.Height + space;
                        xpos = 5;
                    }
                    newButton.Location = new Point(xpos, ypos);
                    xpos += newButton.Width + space;
                    newButton.Click += ItemSelection1;
                    this.FoodMenuPanel.Controls.Add(newButton);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                DtposMenuBS.Sort = "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this a WinForms (desktop) app or a web ASP.NET application?

Comment: Hi Leniel, its a WinForms (desktop) app

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

[Multiline Text as the button label - Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972077/multiline-text-as-the-button-label-windows-forms)

At the time you get the value 10, try to set the button text property with this value. You should do some formatting (adding spaces accordingly) to fit the text in the bottom-right part of the button.

More detailed explanation:

When the dialog box pops up you enter the value 10. When you set this number in the datagrid cell (I think you have some kind of event handler doing this job) you should also set the button's text property `btnSoup.Text = 10` within the same event handler. To align the text in the button, use the link I provided you above.

Comment: Hi Leniel, I'm new to C# programming, just started to learn, could you please clarify relevantly... thanks in advance

Comment: Now you lost me :) i'm cmpletely confused

Comment: Leniel remeber the buttons on form1 (as I explained on my question posted earlier) theay are generated from database records using sql-query...

Comment: OK. I've seen your code. When you do this: `cellContent = ib.Result;` you should also assign `btnSoup.Text = cellContent;`.

Comment: You should be able to get a reference to `btnSoup`. I didn't see the code you're using to create the buttons.

Comment: I cant do  btnSoup.Text = cellContent; because the buttons on Form1 are generated from database

Comment: I know they are generated from database, but they must have a name, ID or something because they're part of the form controls collection. You must find a way of getting a reference to that button.

Comment: here is the code how im creating buttons on form1 and then take the database records and asign values to these buttons

Comment: From what I can see, you should also define the Id or Name property of the button, this way: `newButton.Id = "uniqueNameOfTheButton";`. With this you can get a reference to a specific button by searching the FoodMenuPanel controls collection like this:  `VistaButtonTest.VistaButton newButton = this.FoodMenuPanel.Controls.Find("uniqueNameOfTheButton");`
With a reference to the button you can then assign its Text property.

Comment: can you show me how to do that please, maybe you can modify the code of FoodAddButtons()

Answer (score 0):

You could put a label on top of the button exactly where you want it
and then update the label